# Parse multiple parameters in XSLT tempate

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I need to parse Currency field (**DepositAmount**) in my output XML file and set their decimal points based on input passed via my CSharp class.

1. If input is 1 then the **DepositAmount** fields should have 1 decimal =
   24.0
2. If input is 3 then the **DepositAmount** fields should have 3 decimals = 24.000

I am passing this input to XSLT from within ReportXML as shown below. The **ValuePrecision** is passed via my CSharp class. It will have values of 1 OR 3 OR 4 as mentioned in requirements above. This is the code written in ReportXML file

```
<Amount select="TotalValueofAmt" precision="ValuePrecision"/>
```

Inside the XSLT, I am receiving this input via the **with-param** keyword of XSLT 1.0 as shown below

```
    <xsl:template match="amount">
          <xslo:call-template name="__makeAmount__">

              <xslo:with-param name="str"  select="@select"/>
              <xslo:with-param name="decPrecision" select="@precision"/>

            </xslo:call-template>
    </xsl:template>



<xslo:template name="__makeAmount__">
        <xslo:param name="str"/>
        <xslo:param name="decPrecision"/> 
        <xslo:if test="$decPrecision= 1">
          <xslo:value-of>
            <xsl:attribute name="select">translate(format-number($str,'0.0000'),'.',$__decSep__)</xsl:attribute>
          </xslo:value-of>
        </xslo:if>
        <xslo:if test="$decPrecision= 2">
          <xslo:value-of>
            <xsl:attribute name="select">translate(format-number($str,'0.0'),'.',$__decSep__)</xsl:attribute>
          </xslo:value-of>
        </xslo:if>
        <xslo:if test ="$decPrecision=3">
          <xslo:value-of>
            <xsl:attribute name="select">translate(format-number($str,'0.00'),'.',$__decSep__)</xsl:attribute>
          </xslo:value-of>
        </xslo:if>        
      </xslo:template>
```

However after transformation, the output XML shows a blank. The **decprecision** parameter does not have any value in it. Please advise what is wrong here.
I also tried accessing precision parameter this way

Comment: Please show a reproducible example - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following simplified example:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <entry amount="123" precision="1"/>
    <entry amount="123" precision="2"/>
    <entry amount="123" precision="3"/>
    <entry amount="123" precision="4"/>
</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="entry">
            <amount>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@amount, substring('#.0000', 1, 2 + @precision))"/>
            </amount>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <amount>123.0</amount>
  <amount>123.00</amount>
  <amount>123.000</amount>
  <amount>123.0000</amount>
</output>
```